# AWS Cloudformation: Add Paramater for Userdata

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Need to connect with parameter, making it default and run only 1 command if defaults to yes, should ignore if set to no

```
Paramater
Run Playbook
  Type: AWS::EC2::UserData
   Default

UserData: !Base64
        Fn::Sub:
          - |-
            #!/bin/bash
            xxxxxxxxxx
            xxxxxxxxxx
            xxxxxxxxxx
            ansible-playbook test.yml
```

Comment: You can use the parameter as `${RunPlaybook}` and then check the value in the bash script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options I think, but what I would do is have a cloudformation template like this:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"

Parameters:
    AnsibleCheckRun:
        Description: Environment type.
        Default: true
        Type: String
        AllowedValues: [true, false]
        ConstraintDescription: Must be true or false

Conditions:
    RunAnsible: !Equals [!Ref AnsibleCheckRun, true]

Resources:
    BuildkiteAgentServer:
        Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
        Properties:
            .
            .
            .
            .
        UserData:
            Fn::Base64:
            Fn::Join:
            - ""
            - - "#!/bin/bash\n"
              - !If [RunAnsible, "ansible-playbook test.yml", AWS::NoValue]
```

Syntax may be a little off as this is off the top of my head - but what you're doing is creating a `Condition` section in the template which evaluates your given parameter against an expected value. If the `!Equals` evaluates as a match, then the `ansible-playbook test.yml`will be added into userdata. If the parameter value does not match true, then there will be no Ansible line.

This is the documentation you can have a look at:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html